# Erro 500 (Internal Server Error) Get

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, entity-framework

**ERRO**

GET http://localhost:54446/Tarefas/ListarIntegrantes?equipe=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{

  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>TarefaViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EquipeId, Model.Equipes, "--Selecione", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IntegranteId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="IntegranteId" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Conclusao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Conclusao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ListarIntegrantes(int id)
        {
            GerenciadorContexto ctx = new GerenciadorContexto();
            var lista = new List<EquipedeIntegrante>();

            try
            {
                lista = ctx.EquipedeIntegrantes.Where(m => m.EquipeId == id).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

            return Json(new { Resultado = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#EquipeId").change(function () {

        var value = $("#EquipeId option:selected").val();

        if (value !== 0 || value !== undefined)
        {
            ListarIntegrantes(value);
        }

    })

})

function ListarIntegrantes(value)
{

    var url = "/Tarefas/ListarIntegrantes";
    var data = { equipe: value };
    $("#EquipeId").empty();
    $.ajax({

        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: data
    }).done(function (data) {

        if (data.Resultado.length > 0) {
            var dadosGrid = data.Resultado;
            var opt = "";
            $.each(dadosGrid, function (indice, item) {
                opt += '<option value="' + item["Id"] + '">' + item["Nome"] + '</option>';
            })
            $("#EquipeId").append('<option value="">--Selecione</option>' + opt);
        }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Provavelmente está a entrar nesse `Catch`, não?

Comment: Você deveria detalhar mais sobre o erro. Quando ocorre?
No load da view?
Na controller?
Em qual parte do código?